# ImageMagick montage - создать "ровный" коллаж

Tags: php, imagemagick

Пытаюсь сделать коллаж из изображений, используя ImageMagick (PHP плагин или из консоли).
Дело в том, что в моем случае исходные изображения могут быть разных пропорций - горизонтальные, вертикальные, квадратные. Хотелось бы, чтобы они автоматически изменяли размер и при необходимости обрезались - но резались "от центра". Как делает montage и как хотелось бы видеть результат приложил ниже

[image: пример как делает montage]

[image: как бы хотелось чтобы выглядел результат]

Возможно кто то занимался решением такой проблемы, поделитесь?

Comment: за тебя код написать?

Comment: нет, подсказать какая опция ресайзнет изображение под сетку, не изменяя пропорций

Comment: математически высчитать пропорции, чтобы высота изображения первого стала равной высоте изображения второго, что тут думать? консилиум собрать?

Comment: тебя обучали умничать, не разбираясь в вопросе, или что? в софт заложена эта возможность, без математики, зачем пишешь тут?

Comment: ну так если заложена, почему не используешь?

Comment: потому что не знаю какая, т.к. с imagick и montage знаком ровно несколько часов. логично?

Comment: ну так прочитай описание к каждой функции

Comment: универсальный ответ на русском стаке, к сожалению.